# jQuery live method not working

Tags: jquery, dynamic, live

I am generating img tag dynamically. And performing click event on that. For that  I used jQuery live method. It is working fine in Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome but not working in IE.Here is my Code,

```
 <div class="itemremove"><a href="action">remove</a></div>
```

Using jQuery when the page loaded I am replacing remove text with some image like 'X'.

```
$(".itemremove a").text(""); // deleting text
$(".itemremove a").append("<img class='removeImg' alt='Remove' 
src='remove_item.png'>"); // adding image in that place
```

Next when click on the image event is not firing.

```
 $(".removeImg").live("click", function(){
  alert("Item removed");
 });
```

No alert box in IE But, working in firefox and chrome. Can any one tell me the solution for this?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: And even before jQuery 1.7, use `delegate` (unless you're really stuck way back before 1.4.2).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing closing parenthesis:

```
$(".removeImg").live("click", function(){
  alert("Item removed");
}
); //this one
```

OR try:

```
$(".itemremove a").live("click", function(){
  alert("Item removed");
});
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot close parenthesis in post, but I my code I closed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would place the click on the a:

```
$(".itemremove a").live(...
```

But I would use a background to place the image, and use a text-indent:-10000 for the text. This way it is accesible and you don't have to use javascript which is a second option to css.

Answer (score 0):

.live() is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 (http://api.jquery.com/live/#live-events-map). It's been replaced by .on():

```
$(".itemremove a").on("click", function(){
  alert("Item removed");
});
```

Not that it should effect the result much :)